# How to save sendgrid emails in .eml format rather than using persisted data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, sendgrid

For compliance purposes, I need the ability to download emails. I can download received emails from our exchange servers. But the emails that I send are sent using sendgrid. I couldn't find anything within sendgrid docs which could provide me with such/similar ability. (I see BCC as a option but desperately want to avoid it)

At present, the app persists various email data( `from`, `to`, `cc`, `subject`, `body`) in db and am able to export it to json/xml/pdf files. Unfortunately generating files through db can be viewed as a risk to the truthfulness of data.

I did look through the MIME specifications (although I couldn't find any java library to help me) RFC2048 seems like a fitting standard we can follow.

What should I do to have such functionality?

Comment: At current state of app, I have the liberty to re-architect the entire application and can switch to other mailservers if needed as long as I can have the said functionality